# Searching through a text File with user input

Tags: java, search

I am having an issue. I want to search a text file for multiple matching keywords from a `String []`. I want to output only the sentence that contains one or more of these matching keywords.

So  `String[] keywords = { "going", "What book", "not going ","office", "okay"};`

If a file called `data.txt` contains the sentence " I am going to the office at 6".And the user enters "going and office" I want to print this sentence to console. But as of right now I can only search the file for only one matching keyword. Can someone guide me in the direction to finding multiple keywords in a file.

So here is my method to search the text

```
public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            // break;
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException,
    FileNotFoundException {


String[] keywords = { "going", "What book", "not going ","office", "okay"};


boolean endloop = false;

boolean found = false;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = null;

System.out.println("What's up?");
do {
    System.out.print(" - ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    for (String keyword: keywords) {
        if (input.contains(keyword)) {

            parseFile(keyword);
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out
                .println("I am sorry I do not know");
    }

    break;
}

while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("thanks"));
System.out.println(" Have a good day!");

  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop. Either this way, if one match is sufficient:

```
String line = ...;
String[] search = new String[]{...};

boolean match = false;

for(int i = 0 ; i < search.length && !match; i++)
    match = line.contains(search[i]);
```

or, if all strings must be part of line:

```
String line = ...
String[] search = new String[]{...};

boolean match = true;

for(int i = 0 ; i < search.length && match ; i++)
    match = line.contains(search[i]);
```

Comment: Okay question what does your "..." imply? I am not very proficient in Java, This is all new to me

Comment: "..." is just a replacement for some sort of initialisation. that's no code, i was just too lazy to write out the actual values/generation. just insert the matching code.

Comment: I think i am confused with your code. I am sorry, Can you explain a little more

Comment: `line` holds the line you've read, `search` the strings to search for. in the first example, the search is continued as long as you haven't found a matching string. in the second example, the loop continues, until the algorithm finds a string that isn't part of `line`. after the loop, `match` is true, if the condition is fullfilled (first example: at least one match was found - second example: all strings that are searched were found in `line`)

Comment: But I want to print out the found line to console. How do i do that? Do i system.out.println(match); ?

Comment: no, `match` only indicates whether the condition was fullfilled. just add an if-statement: `if(match)System.out.println(line);`